# Access issues with Google Cloud Functions read access to Google Cloud Firestore Collection in Default Database

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a cloud function in python that would read a collection in Google Cloud Firestore (Native) [not the Realtime Database or Datastore].

I have created a Service Account that has below Roles for the project:
- Project Owner
- Firebase Admin
- Service Account User
- Cloud Functions Developer
- Project Editor

When run on my local I am setting the service account credential in my environment: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

My cloud function is able to access Cloud Storage. I am only having issues with Cloud Firestore.

1. I have tried using both the Client Python SDK and the Admin SDK (Python). The Admin SDK seems to only be available for the realtime database as it requires a Database URL to connect.
2. I have tried running both from my dev machine and as a cloud function.
3. I also changed the Firestore access rules to below for unrestricted access:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to run the same code in the Google Documentation..

```py
from google.cloud import firestore

def process_storage_file(data, context):
    # Add a new document
    db = firestore.Client()
    doc_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(u'alovelace')
    doc_ref.set({
        u'first': u'Ada',
        u'last': u'Lovelace',
        u'born': 1815
        })

    # Then query for documents
    users_ref = db.collection(u'users')
    docs = users_ref.get()

    for doc in docs:
        print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

I am not able to get the Cloud Function to connect to Google Cloud Firestore. I get the error:

line 3, in raise_from google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: **403 Missing or insufficient permissions.**

Both the cloud function and Firestore are in the same GCP Project.

Comment: In the Python code you showed, you never actually defined a Cloud Function entry point.  Where is that?  How do you intend to trigger your code?

Comment: The code is triggered when a file us uploaded to Cloud Storage. The entry point is defined as part of the Cloud Function deploy. That part of the code is working. The exception is only in the code above at line "docs = users_ref.get()"

Comment: The documentation suggests that you define a function for deployment.  I don't see a function here.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage

Comment: I have updated the code with the function.

Answer (score 1):

The service account you specified on the cloud function UI configuration needs to have the Datastore User Role

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you uploaded the service account's credential JSON file along with your code, and that the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable is also set in your Cloud Function's configuration page. (I know uploading credentials is a bad idea, but you need to put the JSON file *somewhere*, if you don't want to use the [Compute Engine default service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#compute_engine_default_service_account).)

Second, you might want to provide a Cloud *Datastore* User role (or a similar one) to your service account, instead of Firebase Admin. It seems that the new Firestore can be accessed with the Cloud Datastore X roles, rather than the Firebase ones.